# Custom "widgets" in html5 app for Ubuntu Phone

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, phone, html5

I've reviewed the [documentation here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/html-5/guides/introduction-to-the-html5-ui-toolkit/) and that helps to get started, but leaves me with a question of how to make a reusable custom html widget.  For example, if I have a list item which contains a bunch of different elements.  I then want to be able to reuse that custom "widget" on different lists.  How can I do that?  Or perhaps that is outside the scope of what's provided - do I need to do that with my own library like angularjs, knockout, etc. perhaps?